# Is there any crossplatform C/C++ lib for files searching? (on hard drive)

Tags: c++, c, search, cross-platform

Is there any crossplatform C\C++ lib for files searching? (on hard drive) What I need is simple - be able to find all images on users computer in all folders and subfolders with sise  >= 200kb.

How to do such thing? Can any one help me? Please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Boost.Filesystem` is a great library. Here is a code I wrote while ago, you can change the search criteria easily once you know the library(you can query the size and the extension):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

void find_file(const path& root, const string& file_name, vector<path>& found_files)
{
        directory_iterator current_file(root), end_file;
        bool found_file_in_dir = false;
        for( ; current_file != end_file; ++current_file)
        {
                if( is_directory(current_file->status()) )
                        find_file(*current_file, file_name, found_files);
                if( !found_file_in_dir && current_file->leaf() == file_name )
                {
                        // Now we have found a file with the specified name,
                        // which means that there are no more files with the same
                        // name in the __same__ directory. What we have to do next,
                        // is to look for sub directories only, without checking other files.
                        found_files.push_back(*current_file);
                        found_file_in_dir = true;
                }
        }
}

int main()
{
        string file_name;
        string root_path;
        vector<path> found_files;

        std::cout << root_path;
        cout << "Please enter the name of the file to be found(with extension): ";
        cin >> file_name;
        cout << "Please enter the starting path of the search: ";
        cin >> root_path;
        cout << endl;

        find_file(root_path, file_name, found_files);
        for( std::size_t i = 0; i < found_files.size(); ++i)
                cout << found_files[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: They have recursive_directory_iterator now, so this can be made even simpler!

Comment: @Cubbi Thanks! I didn't have a look on recent additions to filesystem, but for sure it is better to use the library facilities instead of my code :)

Answer (score 1):

[ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) has a lot of cross-platform wrappers. In your particular case see [ACE_Dirent](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.5/html/ace/classACE__Dirent.html) or [ACE_OS::scandir](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.5/html/ace/namespaceACE__OS.html#a37) / [ACE_OS::opendir](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.5/html/ace/namespaceACE__OS.html#a33) / [ACE_OS::readdir](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.5/html/ace/namespaceACE__OS.html#a34) and friend functions. ACE is very powerful abstraction layer between operating systems. If you need such things then this is the way to go.